# How to configure my CAN filter in list mode?

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, can-bus, stm32f4

I have written some code to transmit/receive CAN messages and I am having some issues with my filter. Firstly I'm going to say that I understand mask mode and have managed to get it working with the following configuration:

```
uint16_t id = 0x12; // 0001 0010
uint16_t mask = 0xFC; // 1111 1100

sFilterConfig.FilterBank=0;
sFilterConfig.FilterMode=CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
sFilterConfig.FilterScale=CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh=id<<5;
sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow=0;
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh=mask<<5;
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow=0;
sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment=0;
sFilterConfig.FilterActivation=ENABLE;

HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &sFilterConfig);
```

This accepts messages with ID 0x1X, where X is 0 to 3. I don't really understand the purpose of the final 2 bits of the ID since they are irrelevant to the mask, is my thinking there correct? Anyway that's not the main issue.

Now having read through RM0090 I'm trying to build a filter that will accept messages with ID 0x120 to 0x1FA with the below code:

```
uint16_t id = 0x120; // 0001 0010 0000
uint16_t mask = 0x1FA; // 0001 1111 1010

sFilterConfig.FilterBank=0;
sFilterConfig.FilterMode=CAN_FILTERMODE_IDLIST;
sFilterConfig.FilterScale=CAN_FILTERSCALE_16BIT;
sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh=mask<<5;
sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow=id<<5;
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh=0;//mask<<5;
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow=0;
sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment=0;
sFilterConfig.FilterActivation=ENABLE;

HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &sFilterConfig);
```

It doesn't work as expected, it only seems to accept IDs 0x120 and 0x00, is my understanding of list mode incorrect or my filter implementation? or both?

**EDIT:**

My understanding of Mask/List mode was wrong. I understand how to use masks but I thought list mode can be used to create a range of acceptable IDs but it seems that you can only use list mode to capture a couple specific IDs. I found [this page](http://schulz-m.github.io/2017/03/23/stm32-can-id-filter/) quite helpful.

As the page I linked above says you can only get ranges in the form 2^N - (2^(N-1) - 1).

My question now becomes what is the point of Mask low/high and filterID low/high? Initially I thought maybe its the lower/higher 16 bits of the 32 bit register but each low/high variable is already uint32 so that idea didn't make sense to me. Any clarity will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: I can't speak for this particular CAN controller, but generally you have an _identifier acceptance filter_ which is a bit sequence that incoming identifiers must match, and an _identifier mask_ which tells which bit in the filter that applies. Various controllers then have all manner of more or less complicated ways to combine acceptance and mask registers. Most often, using these registers create far more problems than they solve. A much better solution is to find a CAN controller with a "mailbox" feature, which is quite common nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are mixing filter and mask:
The filter mask is used to determine which bits in the identifier of the received frame are compared with the filter

If a mask bit is set to a zero, the corresponding ID bit will automatically be accepted, regardless of the value of the filter bit.

If a mask bit is set to a one, the corresponding ID bit will be compare with the value of the filter bit; if they match it is accepted otherwise the frame is rejected.

Comment: Is that not mask mode? So how does List mode differ from mask mode? RM0090 says: 

"In identifier list mode, the mask registers are used as identifier registers. Thus instead of
defining an identifier and a mask, two identifiers are specified, doubling the number of single
identifiers. All bits of the incoming identifier must match the bits specified in the filter
registers."

I haven't really understood what that means and can't find better documentation.

Comment: I am not familar with the RM0090, but I guess you need a complete list of all incomming ID. Not a range from IDx to IDy.